# Check if Windows user or group exists, supporting domain names

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, winapi

I'm interested in check if a given username or group name exist. I need to support AD controllers and multidomain. So the following are valid entries for me:

```
MYDOMAIN\John
John@mydomain.com
OTHERDOMAIN\Administrators
```

So, I want to implement is exactly the same functionality as MS windows implements when you edit the permissions of a folder, then you type a name and click **"Check names"** button.

Is there a Windows API that work as described in a single call?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A quick search gave me [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.FindUsersByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.findusersbyname%28v=vs.100%29). Is this what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, what I'm looking for is something similar to LookupAccountSid

Comment: There's [LookupAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LsaLookupNames2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).